# Can I restore object rotations from an already applied-rotations mesh?

Tags: objects, transforms

If I create a sphere (Shift+A) in Blender and rotate it various degrees in x, y, or z, these rotations show up under the N -> Item -> Transforms tab, and the object's local XYZ are determined based on those transforms. Once I apply the rotations, these values reset to zero. How can I restore those transforms to an already transform-applied mesh? Is it possible to do this with scale as well?

Comment: Have you got any way of deducing, from the mesh, (not its history,) what the object transforms should be?

Comment: @RobinBetts Probably. The object in question is a complete sphere, like the default ones from Shift+A.

Comment: Use a method like [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/218885/35559), creating an orientation from the 2 pole vertices of the sphere, followed by RX-90, if you want the Z pole-to-pole.

Comment: @RobinBetts well. Robin, although i am a big fan of you and i upvoted your comment - this is not exactly true. Because you don't know whether the UV Sphere is upside down.... ;) sorry, couldn't resist. :D

Comment: @Chris When I was about 10 years old, a geography teacher drew a circle on the blackboard with an arrow through it, saying: 'This is North. It points up, like this.' I stuck my hand up: 'Sir! Sir!  Not necessarily!'  I was sent out and made to stand in the corner of the lobby outside for the rest of the class.

Comment: What a bad teacher. I feel with you!!!

Comment: @Chris A lot of my teachers suffered in WWII. This one had been a Japanese POW. No time for clever-dicks. In retrospect, gotta cut'em some slack.

Comment: Even so lot's of people might think intelligent people have an easier life - i don't think so. ;)

Comment: @RobinBetts To return to the matter at hand, it took me a while to figure out what the "orientations dropdown" in your linked answer was (for later readers, it's the thing that normally reads Global next to the "transform origins"(?) dropdown with Median, Individual Origins, etc), and longer still to get the axes aligned as desired (they came in with the wrong directions... probably that "is the sphere upside down" issue), but it eventually worked; thanks!

Comment: Sorry about the sidetrack.. glad you cracked it! It's hard to find shorthand ..  I suppose I should use the tooltips?:Header > 'Transform Orientation' and Header > Transform Pivot Point'..  They're so central to _everything_, that references get lazy. Will fix.

Comment: Haha, yeah, shorthand seems to me like something learned or made up over time and hard to compile and share for novices. I identify what things are based on tooltips or what they read, hence how I described the "orientations dropdown" in the prior comment.